# How to decide a dropdown value selection based on confirmation from a popup in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to display a popup with "yes" or "no" radio buttons and a save button
So when a dropdown is selected the popup needs to be displayed and when the user selects "yes" and click on "save" the dropdown needs to be updated with the currently selected value else when "no" is selected it should revert to the old value which was already selected in the dropdown.

I've used the onchange event for calling it in the Client side but I am not sure whether it is easier to do it in the Server or the Client side

```xml
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInitialIncidentType" runat="server" onchange="prioritySelection(this)" Width="210px">
    <asp:ListItem Text="<--Select-->" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Initial-P1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Initial-P2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

```js
function prioritySelection(sender) {
    $find("ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_ModalPopupIncidentTypeChange").show();                
}
```

NOTE:`"ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_ModalPopupIncidentTypeChange"` is a AjaxModelpopup which has two RADIO buttons "Yes" and "No" and a SAVE button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean something like that?

```js
//previous option value
var prevOption = null;
//get previous option
$('#myselect').on('click', function(){
  prevOption = $(this).val();
});
//modify default change behavior with confirmation dialog
$('#myselect').on('change', function(){
  $(this).val(confirm('Are you sure about selection?') ? $(this).val() : prevOption);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option selected disabled></option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
  <option value="option5">option5</option>
</select>
```

I don't know which exactly method you use to throw pop-up, but my code delivers general idea, I believe.

Comment: This kinda answers but still I need to trigger it when the radio button is checked and on the click of save from the popup.

Comment: Come on, that's just one tiny step forward! https://jsfiddle.net/rtnhgLao/

Comment: Thanks Yevgen Gorbunkov for the answer!